# How to use component schemas for primitive types in OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger, openapi, jsonschema, connexion

I want to create component schemas for single primitive key value pairs in order to reuse them. I found two ways, but neither works for my 2 requirements. The first solution nests the primitive value in an object with a single required key.

```yaml
portComponent:
  type: object
  properties:
    port:
      type: integer
      minimum: 1
      maximum: 65535
  require:
    - port
```

The alternative is directly defining the primitive value like:

```yaml
portComponent:
  type: integer
  minimum: 1
  maximum: 65535
```

---

My goals are

1. Primitive values are always used with the same key. This reduces errors and code generators produce exactly one code class per key-value pair. Only #1 allows this
2. I can specify if the primitive components are required. #1 only allows to `require` the whole component via `allOf`. But I can not specify them as optional. #2 values are added via a new key in the surrounding component which I can easily add to `require`. But then code generation doesn't work and keys are not enforced.

To provide another perspective on the question:
**How can you add a component schema (optional or required) to another component without nesting it inside a new property or always requiring it via allOf or similar?**

---

Updates: I use following minimal example with the OpenAPI docker generator "openapitools/openapi-generator-cli:v7.0.0" for python-flask.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: sandbox
tags:
  - name: Information
    description: System information
paths:
  /portValueOnly:
    get:
      operationId: get_port_value_only
      tags:
        - Information
      responses:
        200:
          description: Provides port
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/portComponent'
  /portWrapped:
    get:
      operationId: get_port_wrapped
      tags:
        - Information
      responses:
        200:
          description: Provides port
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  port:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/portComponent'
  /information:
    get:
      operationId: get_all_system_information
      tags:
        - Information
      responses:
        200:
          description: Provides all system information
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/systemInformation'
  /character:
    get:
      operationId: get_character
      tags:
        - Information
      responses:
        200:
          description: Provides a character
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/enumComponent'
components:
  schemas:
    systemInformation:
      type: object
      properties:
        character:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/enumComponent'
        port:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/portComponent'
    enumComponent:
      type: string
      enum:
      - "a"
      - "b"
    portComponent:
      type: integer
      minimum: 1
      maximum: 65535
    thingWithTypo:
      type: object
      properties:
        pord:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/portComponent'
```

The route `/portWrapped` leads to the generation of a `get_port_wrapped200_response.py` but the portComponents used inside of other components use raw strings. I understand why this happens and I can live with it. I will implement primitive routes like `portValueOnly` instead to avoid these generations.

<strike>Sadly I encountered a new problem with specifying primitive value components without a wrapping object: enums. The generator doesn't seem to be able to handle e.g. `enumComponent`. If used in other components, e.g. `systemInformation` it works. The generated code file for the standalone enum is broken</strike>:
Edit: this was recently [fixed][1]. I keep it here as I only found the issue by reading the release notes after it worked with the latest version. Google did not find anything when searching for OpenAPI and `NUMBER_&#39;a&#39` despite it being mentioned in the issue.

```
<...>
NUMBER_&#39;a&#39; = 'a'
NUMBER_&#39;b&#39; = 'b'
<...>


  [1]: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/16576
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define your components and then require them when necessary in the individual schemas where they are used.

does this answer your question?

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.3",
    "info": {
        "title": "",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "portComponent": {
                "type": "integer",
                "minimum": 1,
                "maximum": 65535
            },
            "thing": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "port": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/portComponent"
                    }
                }
            },
            "anotherThing": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "port": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/portComponent"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["port"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly not as this is my second proposed solution with the mentioned drawbacks that the key for the "port-value" could be different in different components annd code generators will generate multiple port structures if the port component is also used standalone, e.g. directly in a response without a wrapping component.

Comment: The portComponent should only be generated once and then it's reused by reference only.  Which generator are you using?  Can you share a real world example?

Comment: I updated my question with a minimal example and the used generator. I also now think that I can avoid my multiple generated structures issue, but I encountered new problems, which probably should be raised as an Issue at the generator's repo